# How to download generated QR code of googleapis using PHP?

Tags: php, html, qr-code

Can somebody tell me what is the problem why I can't download the QR Code I generated?

Here's the code

PHP --

HTML --

```
            <div class="mb-3">
                <img src="<?php echo $output['img'] ?>" alt="QR Code" width="100%" height="100%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3"  href="<?php echo $output['img'] ?>   "  download>Download</a>
            </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    if ($_POST['width'] != "") {
        $width = $_POST['width'];
    } else {
        $width = "250";
    }
    if ($_POST['height'] != "") {
        $height = $_POST['height'];
    } else {
        $height = "250";
    }
    $width = $_POST['width'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $url = "chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs={$width}x{$height}&chl={$data}";
    $output['img'] = $url;
} 

?>
```

Comment: I think it triggers when I click the button where I generates the QR Code. What should I do?

Comment: Why put spaces in `"<?php echo $output['img'] ?>   "`?

Comment: You should remove all trailing spaces in `"<?php echo $output['img'] ?>   "`, or they will be part of the link URL. You should also include the scheme part (`https://`) in the URL: `https://chart.googleapis.com/...` or the client will treat it as a relative URL for your application.

Comment: I did what you guys suggested but nothing works :<

Comment: So what actually happens? It's easier to help if you explain the current behaviour and what debugging you've done.

Comment: I still can't download the qr code

Comment: I get redirected to the URL when I hit download link.

Comment: If you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a, you will see: _"`download` only works for same-origin URLs, or the `blob:` and `data:` schemes"_. If you want to offer that as a download, then you need to create a proxy in PHP that downloads that URL and returns it to the client instead of linking them to a different origin (domain).

Comment: I see, but I don't know how to do that since I'm only a beginner. :<

Comment: can you teach me how?